# Trying to implement Generics for HTTP Request swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, alamofire, objectmapper

I am trying to use generics to implement the request / response in a Base class, so that the derived classes need not have to bother about the gory implementation details.

```
class mNoxHttpClient {

    var apiUrl      : String = ""
    var operation   : Int = -1
    var postData    : AnyObject

    var responseData : AnyClass

    init (apiUrl:String, operation:Int, postData:AnyObject) {
        self.apiUrl         = apiUrl
        self.operation      = operation
        self.postData       = postData
    }

    func doInBackground() {
        let fullURL = God.getFullURL(apiURL: self.apiUrl)
        Alamofire.request(fullURL, method: .post).responseObject { (response: DataResponse<AnyClass>) -> ()
            if (response != nil && response.result != nil && response.result.value != nil) {
                responseData = (response.result.value) 
            }
        }
    }

    func doAfterBackgroundCompletes() {
        assert(false, "This method must be overriden by the subclass")
    }

    func execute() {
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
            self.doInBackground()

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.doAfterBackgroundCompletes()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I need to get my method `doInBackground` to run in the background. Before that I am trying to get `Alamofire`to send the request and return the response to a Mappable object so that I can type cast the response later in a derived class.

As of now, this line is giving me an error
`Alamofire.request(fullURL, method: .post).responseObject { _ in (response: DataResponse<Mappable>) -> ()`

Error

> Cannot convert value of type 'DataRequest' to closure result type 'AnyClass' aka ()

**Edit**

I modified my code a bit

```
Alamofire.request(fullURL).responseObject { (response: DataResponse<AnyClass>) in
                responseData = response.result.value
        }
```

Now I get a error

> Value of optional type 'AnyClass?' cannot be unwrapped, did you mean to use '!' or '?' ?

Comment: `Mappable` is a protocol. How does `DataResponse` know what's the type it has to infer since you're passing a protocol?

Comment: I have chagned it to AnyClass, ideally I need a class reference here so that the derived class can define the response POJO

Comment: I don't know much about ObjectMapper, but passing the generic parameter to the `doInBakcground()` function could be the solution. `func doInBackground<T: Mappable>()` and then define the response as `DataResponse<T>`